# Placing an image into a HTML div after ClickOn using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple HTML page, I want an image to appear in HTML after the user selects an option. There are a number of different images which can appear.

```
  <img
        id="myImg"
        src="Image.jpg"
        width="107"
        height="98"
      />
```

The JS code works fine the image loads after the user clicks on an option on the HTML page, but I also need it to update on another HTML page, when we go to this page, the image does not update.

```
function Option1() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").src =
    "option1.jpg";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by "also need it to update on another html", Please explain your complete workflow and desired outcome.

Comment: you can achieve this by doing this

```<button onclick="Option1()">Option1</button>```

Comment: @VimalPatel I have a HTML site with 2 pages. Page 1 has the option to select and the image appears below. But I also want this to appear on Page 2.

Comment: @Rilla that is how I have done it. The button is working fine as intended, I just need the image to also appear on page 2 after the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can transfer data from one page to another on the same site, including:

- cookies
- query strings
- hash fragments
- IndexedDB

but one of the simplest, cleanest and most straightforward techniques is:

- WebStorage (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

which acts as a kind of inter-page memory for a website.

In this situation, once the user selects an image on one page, you can store it with:

```
localStorage.setItem('selectedImage', 'my-image.jpg');
```

and when another page loads, you can retrieve the selected image with:

```
localStorage.getItem('selectedImage');
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thank you, I will try localStorage and see can I get it to work

Comment: So after the user has selected the option, inside that function I will add localStorage.setItem('selectedImage', 'my-image.jpg');


Then how would I make that appear on the HTML on the second page? Apologies I am only a beginner.

Comment: I now have it working using the localStorage option you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Great work, @coding123ire - well done for persevering until you got there! You may have seen - but if you haven't already, you need to know this - that you can use your _browser developer tools_ at any point to find out manually what keys and values are held in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

The page you go to doesn't know anything about the settings and changes you made on the page you came from.

You will somehow have to pass the changes made on the first page to the second page.

This you could do by setting a *cookie* (or using *localStorage*) with the name of the image and reading that back in the second page, or by passing the name of the new image in the URL of the second page in a URL *query string*, and retrieving it with `URLSearchParams` or another method of your choice.

Another option would be to generate the second page in the JavaScript on your first page.

Comment: thanks for your answer I will have a look at using localStorage.

Comment: You may also want to vote, and/or more importantly, accept one of the answers to prevent the question remaining open. That is, if you do accept an answer as "the" answer , of course 8-).